# How can a brush which is used for the BackgroundProperty of a WPF control be given a margin?

Tags: wpf, brushes

In WPF, I have a `TextBox` with a `BackgroundProperty` set to a custom brush. I want to give this brush some kind of visual buffer from the border of the `TextBox`. The brush is a `GlyphRunBrush` which acts much like an `ImageBrush`, but has a rasterized glyph run as the brush source.

How can I do this?

*Example:* 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to apply a transformation to the brush itself, like so:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/MyApp;component/Search.ico"
                    AlignmentX="Right" Stretch="Uniform">
            <ImageBrush.Transform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <TranslateTransform X="-5"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </ImageBrush.Transform>
        </ImageBrush>
    </TextBox.Background>
</TextBox>
```

You could also try changing the width on the brush's `Viewport` property, but since you're aligning it on the right side, that may be more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Nice trick. A combination of a `ScaleTransform` with 0.8 scale factor and a `TranslateTransform` scaled and bound to the width of the textbox to keep the glyph to the right worked.